# R plotly draw in label zone

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Is it possible to plot shapes below the x-"label axis". E.g for:

```
h <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
plot_ly(
  h, name = "20", type = "waterfall", 
  x = ~gear,
  textposition = "outside", 
  text = c("Gear 3", "Gear 4", "Gear 5"),
  y= ~mpg)
```

To have red boxes like below. Ideally I would want those boxes to be aligned with eachother and the above boxes, but my paint skills are non-existing.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `add_annotations` to place boxes outside of the plotting area. After some trial and error:

1. Set `yref = "paper"`
2. Set `y = 0`. (Aligns the boxes with the x-axis)
3. Shift the boxes using `yshift = -xxxx`. (Shifts the boxes outside)
4. Increase the bottom margin using `layout(margin = list(b = xxxx))` (Makes space for the boxes)

Try this:

```
library(plotly)

h <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
plot_ly(
  h, name = "20", type = "waterfall", 
  x = ~gear,
  textposition = "outside", 
  text = c("Gear 3", "Gear 4", "Gear 5"),
  y= ~mpg) %>% 
  add_annotations(
    x = ~gear,
    y = 0,
    yshift = -100,
    bgcolor = I("red"),
    bordercolor = I("black"),
    width = 200,
    height = 20,
    yref = "paper",
    text = c("Gear 3", "Gear 4", "Gear 5"),
    showarrow = FALSE
  ) %>% 
  layout(margin = list(b = 100))
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you!
Is it possible to do something similar if x is discrete, and then with a possible grouping of some x-variables.
Eg. If I show all three green boxes, but their x-values are "Gear3", "Gear4" and "Gear5" respectively. However in addition there is only 2 red boxes. One box for both Gear3 and Gear4 (spanning their entire width) and one for Gear5?

Comment: Hi @mfindinge. Both things are possible. Try it out. (; I just checked. 1. Discrete x-axis is no issue. 2. If you want boxes for only two categories just say so like x = c(1, 3), then adjust the widths, and make use xhift e.g. xhift = c(50, -50) will shift one box to the right the other to the left.

Comment: I can use the index order as an x-value. However I would like the boxes to:
1) Dynamically fit the width to each group of discrete x-values.
2) Dynamically fit the height to each text (maybe with some min/max size).
Number 1 is resized upon window / app resizing which also will impact number 2.
Is there a way to link the width and height to the databar-sizes?
EDIT: Didn't see your comment, will read first.

Comment: ((: Try it out. Haven't done this before. Not sure how much can be done with dynamic heights and widths. But you can link the height to the size of the databars e.g. height = ~ 2 * mpg

Comment: I will goof around with it! Maybe creating a function for the width. Thank you so much!